# Disconnect and confusion between job search filters and job match preferences

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm asking this question because there really should be a way to cookie or store and save the job search filters:

[image]

Every time I tab onto anything on stackoverflow these filters are reset.  If I click "search companies" and return to "search jobs" this data is lost again.  I find myself having to select these parameters every single time...

But wait you say you have the job match preferences setting in your profile...but I don't believe these work correctly...I have these set in my profile yet the job search filters may / may not override them?

But then when I check my job search preferences and do not set the job search filters the results I get do not match the criteria I have in my job match preferences.

This is very confusing...why doesnt the job search filters (the picture from above) automatically set your job match preferences?  In addition these ones:

[image]

Or even better why doesn't it such that when I go to "search jobs" the settings from my job match preferences automatically load these filters so I know what I am searching on?  Right now it is very misleading how any of this works.  Is it using my job match preferences or is it using my job search filters?  Which one overrides the other one and why are they not in sync?

Ideal scenario is you get rid of this multiple way of doing this.  Whatever changes you make to one it saves to the other...they should be just one setting after all.  And when you first bring up the ui "search jobs" whatever is in your "job match preferences" (this is in your SO profile) should automatically load those filters that look like tags (the blue squares).  It should do it automatically based on what I have already defined.

If I remove something it should remove it from my preference and REMEMBER this value.  Otherwise i find myself repeating searches over and over.

Answer (score 1):

> There really should be a way to cookie or store and save the job search filters

There is ... kind of.

You can use the "Recent searches" in the right pane to access your previously used search filters.

[image]

> Is it using my job match preferences or is it using my job search filters? Which one overrides the other one and why are they not in sync?

Job search filters are *filters* (indeed!): they allow you to restrict the search results to certain criteria.

Job match preferences, on the other hand, help us better understand what you're looking for, *more generally*. They are currently used in two ways:

- To sort the search results when in "matches" sort.
- To sort the jobs in the job alert emails, and to decide which jobs to send you if there are too many.

To give a concrete example, if you search for [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) jobs in New York City (using search filters), and your match preferences indicate that you like [redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redis), jobs with both [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) and [redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redis) will be bumped closer to the top of the list.

As you pointed out, this system is not perfect, and we are always looking for ways to make it better.

One of the plans we have is to offer you, after you've entered search criteria, to populate your job match preferences using these criteria.

Comment: I can't say I like this answer 100% as there still is a lot of confusion coming from it.  You explaining it helps but don't you think thats a lot of explaining for something that would just seem to work so natural based on my points above?  You did mention you guys are working on this more so I take it maybe my points will be taken a bit into consideration?

Comment: I agree this is not very natural, and we're trying to fix it. We will take your points into consideration when we discuss it in more details, thank you for your feedback!

Comment: PS: I did not downvote you!