# How can I stop getting job recommendations from my company's internet location?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

My global company has a corporate internet that only hops off to the public network from one data centre in Chicago. Aside from the annoying other effects of this it means that I get a lot of job recommendations from SO that are in Chicago. Is there any setting I can change in my profile that will prevent SO from assuming I live where my internet is accessed from?

I found another question [Disconnect and confusion between job search filters and job match preferences](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340973/disconnect-and-confusion-between-job-search-filters-and-job-match-preferences) that shows a button for "Always include my current location" but that isn't available on my profile? I need that. Where did it disappear to?

Comment: There is no setting currently.  The setting to "Always include my current location" is the location you have set in your edit profile.  Enter your location and save it.  The jobs ui is very confusing and there are way too many options to chose from.

Comment: Question, which recommendations are you referring to? the ones you receive on our emails?

Comment: I meant the jobs that come up on the sidebar, and in the profile.

Comment: In the U.K. we have terrible IP location lookup, I guess because of the size of our little country. This often means when accepting two-factor security prompts from other providers it has you placed in a completely different city.

Comment: [There was talk about changing this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317083/542251) but as I understand it this simply isn't supported at the moment

Comment: @Sinc alright, so my reply has two parts. Profile/email (they use the same code): we've updated the recommendations that it only uses the IP that was used to log in (or that you're currently using) if you don't have a location in your preferences. Ads: The ads team is prioritizing doing the same thing on the ads on the sidebar. I don't have an ETA on that change, so I'll go with 6-8 weeks ;)

Comment: @g3rv4 Thanks for the ETA. I'll hold you to it. ;-) 
I have to say that the duplicate questions doesn't have a very effective title for finding it as the answer to my problem. But I guess now my question can be the search result and point to the obscure question. Maybe even more people will upvote me.