# Why does SO Jobs show me offers way off my entered locations?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

I have currently set my job search preferences to some cities, all in the red circle. Why do I get an offer for Würzburg (Germany), which is over 300km away from me? I have **not** checked the box *"Willing to work remotely"*, either.

### [image: Map]

### [image: Job Offer]

[image: Job Location Preferences]

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth confusingly the 'ads' shown in this view are not real ads - they're fed directly from job search. This is an area that we're working on to make consistent but we're not there yet.

Comment: Possibly because based on the salary calculator you should be earning 350k... which is plenty to pay for your private helicopter.

Comment: It's Würzburg - you're on their radar:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your job preferences are *not* used as filters. They are used as hints for the kinds of jobs you are interested in and they feed into our matching algorithm. Aurélien goes into this in a little more detail [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340973/disconnect-and-confusion-between-job-search-filters-and-job-match-preferences).

We use the locations you enter as [one of many factors](https://medium.com/@aurelien.gasser/a-dive-into-stack-overflow-jobs-search-62bc6e628f83) to help weight jobs and that is then used to sort the jobs in the order that we think is most applicable to you.

So, in short, this is not a bug, but by design. That's not to say we won't consider changing it, I'll raise it with the team.

Comment: We've had this same question so many times that it warrants a change.